# Python - Avoid cumsum on duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

Here is a sample dataframe, `df`:

```
D_ID   E_ID  CAT1 CAT2 
1      10    1    0
1      10    1    0
1      11    0    1  
1      12    1    0
```

Using the following code:

```
event_agg_count = df.groupby('D_ID')['CAT1', 'CAT2'].cumsum()
```

I'm able to calculate the cumsum but i end up with:

```
D_ID   E_ID  CAT1 CAT2 
1      10    1    0
1      10    2    1
1      11    2    1  
1      12    3    1
```

Where, i really want:

```
D_ID   E_ID  CAT1 CAT2 
1      10    1    0
1      10    1    1
1      11    1    1  
1      12    2    1
```

I thought to do a merge but I dont have a key to merge on.

Let me know if you have any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: What if CAT2 was [2, 2, 1, 1]?

Comment: For the final df?

Comment: Yes//////\\\\\\////\\\\

Comment: No, I'd want it to be as is. I need the cumsum

Comment: I asked what the output in the final df would be if CAT2 in the input was [2, 2, 1, 1]

Comment: it wouldn't be. I should have specified and I have updated the dataframes. Assume they are one hot encoded vectors

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here coming from google since I was looking for a way to `cumsum` while ignoring duplicates based on another column.

By now I think I found a solution so I'm posting it here just in case someone else is looking for the same thing

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 10, 1, 0], [1, 10, 1, 0], [1, 11, 0, 1], [1, 12, 1, 0]],
    columns=["D_ID", "E_ID", "CAT1", "CAT2"],
)
dftmp = df.copy()
dftmp.CAT1 *= ~dftmp[["E_ID", "CAT1"]].duplicated(keep="first")
dftmp.groupby('D_ID')['CAT1', 'CAT2'].cumsum()

Out[24]: 
   CAT1  CAT2
0     1     0
1     1     0
2     1     1
3     2     1
```

Note that the CAT2 column output is a bit different to what's posted in the question. However, I assume the output in the question above has a type since the cumsum should have `0` in the second row based on the given example data